# How get resource name in ResourceNotFoundException of AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2

Tags: c#, servicestack, amazon-dynamodb, pocodynamo

i am working with [ServiceStack.Aws](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo) and i am getting an ResourceNotFoundException, but i can't see the resource name that it looking for. ¿The resource name are sent in the exception? ¿How can i get it?

My model class is (table and index name exists)

```
[DynamoDBTable("SOME-TABLE-NAME")]
    public class Company
    {
        [DynamoDBHashKey]
        public string CompanyId { get; set; }

        [DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexHashKey("SOME-INDEX-NAME")]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }

        public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

My code is

```
var awsDb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
            var db = new PocoDynamo(awsDb);

            db.RegisterTable<Company>();
            try
            {
                db.PutItem<Company>(new Company
                {
                    Address = "Some address #some number",
                    CompanyId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    DocumentNumber = "11.222.333-4",
                    FullName = "Some company name",
                    ShortName = "ShortName"
                });
            }
            catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

In my app.config i have (path and profile name exists. Region is ok too)

```
<aws region="us-east-1" profileName="profile-name" profilesLocation="some-path\certificados.txt">
  </aws>
```

Edit: The problem is that ServiceStack don't use AWS Attributes. So, i change DynamoDBTable to Alias and all work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ServiceStack.Aws's PocoDynamo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo) automatically retries temporary exceptions behind-the-scenes so the original AWS exception may have been retried. I've just added an `ExceptionFilter` in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo#managed-dynamodb-client) which will let you inspect each Exception thrown by AWS DynamoDB client with:

```
var dynamo = new PocoDynamo(awsDynamoClient) { 
    ExceptionFilter = ex => ex.Message.Print();
};
```

The ExceptionFilter is available from v4.0.61 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Also `[DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexHashKey]` attribute has no effect in PocoDynamo, please see the docs on [creating Global Indexes with PocoDynamo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/PocoDynamo#global-secondary-indexes).